# JavaScript - nubie, window.onlaod and IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/RZTF9uda8Cw2YQx8Gs1Y?p=preview

Its a simple event on a button

With window.onload it works but not with the IIFE.

I thought the IIFE would run once its created so is that not like once the window has loaded?

```
    // (function(){

    //   var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');

    //   btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //     alert('Hi');
    //   })

    // })();


    window.onload = function(){

      var btn = document.getElementById('btn2');

      btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('Hi');
      })

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the IIFE would run once its created

Yes, of course. (It’s kinda in the name already …)

> so is that not like once the window has loaded?

And that is the *problem*.

Your script resource is embedded in the head, meaning at the time it is executed, the HTML element you are trying to select by its id does not exist yet.

So you either need to execute this after the element exists (window load, DOMContentReady), or embed the external script resource *after* the relevant HTML elements. (Placing scripts at the end of body is a general performance recommendation anyway.)

Comment: "would run once its created" — For a value of "it" equal to *the function* and not *the element*.

Comment: @Quentin yes, of course; I assumed that’s what OP meant as well.